# Reflection.Emit Performance

Tags: emit

Here's a simple question.

Let's say we want to unroll a looping method such as:

```
public int DoSum1(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i <= n; i++)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Into a method performing simple additions only:

```
public int DoSum2( )
{
    return 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20;
}
```

[http://etutorials.org/Programming/Programming+C.Sharp/Part+III+The+CLR+and+the+.NET+Framework/Chapter+18.+Attributes+and+Reflection/18.3+Reflection+Emit/][1]

Logically, we're going to need code to create `DoSum2` in IL at some point.
In this IL generation code we will perform an actual loop with the same iteration count than the unoptimized method.

**What's the point of creating a super fast dynamic method if the code required to generate it will use a similar amount of time to execute???**

Perhaps you can give an example, when it worths using Emit in a similar case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the point of creating a super fast dynamic method if the code required to generate it will use a similar amount of time to execute

This isn't really specific to `Reflection.Emit`, but to runtime code generation in general, so I will answer accordingly.

First, I do not recommend using code generation simply to perform micro-optimizations that compilers normally perform like loop unrolling.  Let the JIT compiler do it's job.

Second, you are right in that there is usually little point in generating code that will only execute once.  The time required to emit and JIT compile the IL is not insubstantial.  You should only bother generating code if it will be executed many times.

Now, there definitely *are* cases where runtime code generation can prove beneficial.  In fact, it's a technique I leverage heavily.  I work in an electronic trading environment where it is necessary to process very high volumes of dynamic data.  This introduces several concerns, the most significant being memory usage and throughput.

Our trading application needs to keep a lot of data in memory, so the footprint of each record is critical.  Dynamic data structures like maps/dictionaries are less efficient than "POCO" classes with optimized field layouts and, depending on the design, may require boxing some values.  I avoid this overhead by generating client-side storage classes once the shape of the data is known.  In effect, the memory layout is as it would have been had I known the shape of the data at compile time.

Throughput is a major issue as well; (de)serializing dynamic data often involves some additional introspection and extra layers of indirection.  Need to serialize a record?  OK, first you need to query what the fields are.  Then, for each field, you need to determine its type, then select a serializer for that type, and  then invoke the serializer.  If your data structure has optional fields, you may need to do some additional pre-processing, like figuring out the size of a presence map, and which bits in the presence map correspond to which fields.  If you need to process a *ton* of data, all that overhead becomes a real problem.  I avoid this overhead by generating specialized (de)serializers on both the server side and client side.  Since the serializers are generated on demand, they can know the exact shape of the data, and read/write that data as efficiently as a hand-optimized serializer.  When you have a high volume of data updating at very high frequencies, this can make a huge difference.

Now, keep in mind that we're something of an edge case.  Most applications do not have the aggressive memory and throughput requirements that ours has, so runtime code generation isn't necessary.  You should only go that route if you *really* need it, and you have exhausted all other possibilities.  Although it can help with performance, generated code can be *very* difficult to debug and maintain.

Comment: "This isn't really specific to Reflection.Emit" :
Right I could've used CodeDom instead though slower.

I guess the whole idea is that such performance optimization is for reapeated use of the same generated assembly. ...in my example the method is not re-useable.

""POCO" classes with optimized field layouts":

I wonder if you're talking about using shorter adresses in MSIL? Otherwise please explain.

The example you mentioned regarding serialization is very interesting. Indeed you would've to run a lot of conditional reflection code.

Comment: Regarding my POCO comment, I simply meant that if the underlying data is stored in appropriately typed fields, as opposed to a sparse map/dictionary, the footprint is more compact.  The runtime can arrange the fields to eliminate unnecessary padding, and you don't end up with unused slots like you might have in a hashtable (not to mention unnecessary boxed values).